# How to ask questions with set of answers you want to discuss

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta, self-answer

Say one has a question about a UI-related issue encountered on Stack Overflow. It's a question about usability, so there's no right answer, but it's possible to discuss multiple options and decide on a probable best solution.

What's the best way to ask such a question on meta, if the user asking also has an opinion about the best choice? Should they:

- include their preference in the question itself
- post a self-answer with their preference
- list every option they can think of in a separate answer, even though there's one they prefer

Comment: Debates fuelled by personal preference are contemptible citizens and should simply be avoided.

Comment: @Mr. Dissapointement, a question with a set of answers is not the same as "debates fuelled by personal preference". For example - a question "how can we fetch data without reloading the page" can have several answers, it even perfectly legal to discuss which answer is best fit.

Comment: I notice this is related to asking questions on meta; apparently anything goes here, what's the worry?

Answer (score 0):

> How to ask questions with set of answers you want to discuss

I'm already confused.

Do you want to ask a purely subjective question (lots of right answers)?

- This can be permitted, but it has to still be in the range of what we do on the stacks.

Do you want to ask a question that objectively has more than one right answer?

- This sounds like an anomaly and will be hard to answer, revise your question and make it so there's one good answer. Use tagging to relate them together.

Do you want to ask a question that really is just a bit of discussion and you don't quite have a blog of your own reknown?

- This is what I get when I read your Q.

---

So ... can you help me clarify and nail this one down?

Comment: yep, see my example in the comment to Mr. Dissapointment.

Comment: I don't get it. Please draw me a picture instead. You have to use your describing words, as I did in my answer.

Comment: OK, let me try again. Imagine following question - "Post to Meta differs from that one  on the Stackoverflow: on meta we have preset of tags, at least one of them should be used. How can we improve UI regarding this fact?" Off the top of my head, we can propose sorta of question wizard - first, choose, one of obligatory tags, than ask you question. We can use another approach and to make inserting this tags a one-click action. There are lot of approaches we can discuss. None of them is **the only true one**

Comment: There is always a way to present a question in such a way as to elicit one particular answer. There is also always a way to present a question that is just for discussion. Can you not provide a concrete example (feel free to edit your Q above) that offers us the type of question you want to ask as well as two or three answers that you think fit the bill?

Comment: I've asked concrete question, if you don't like it, feel free to downvote. The aim of this question was not to convince you in anything.